# Past Continuous vs Past Simple (limited timeframe)

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

A friend of mine was taking her English exam the other day (she is a chemistry student) and she had to talk about her work in a laboratory (they have to do a lab-project for 2 weeks every semester) that she had done for 2 weeks before that exam

She wanted to tell the examiner what the main goal of her laboratory work was,
so she said:

> "***I worked** on changing the formula of...*"

However, the teacher (non-native) replied that it should be:

> "***I was working** on changing the formula of*.."

saying that here we have a regular action in a limited period of time and thus we can't use simple past here, otherwise, it would suggest that "working on changing the formula" is  part of her lifestyle and doesn't fit in well with the timeframe of a 2-week lab work

1. Which one is more natural in this context? Are both correct? What is the difference?

Also, I thought that the past continuous **always** implied some interruption after the continuous action like

> "I was working on changing the formula but then they stopped financing
> and I never finished my laboratory project"

"working" started in the past and lasted for some time but before the 2-week timeframe expired, investors stopped financing (interruption) and she didn't finish her project

2. Is my understanding correct?
3. Is the teacher's explanation/argumentation relevant?
4. Do native speakers perceive "worked" as regular or singular action in this context?

Comment: was working is for a description. The teacher was **wrong**. [for the last two weeks] I worked on x. No doubt about it. I was working on x during the summer but now am not.

Comment: (While I never argue with Lambie,) I doubt that most English speakers would have noticed the difference. For the two weeks before the exam, she **was working on it, worked on it, had worked on it**. They are all idiomatic. The choice might depend on the construction.  At best, the teacher is nit-picking!

Comment: do you perceive "worked" as a regular action (that lasted for some time) or singular action in this context:
"I worked on changing the formula..."

Comment: @RonaldSole Of course,both are grammatical or idiomatic, but both are not used in the same speech contexts. If you are *asked**, "So what were **you doing** this summer?", you would go with the ing. If you are asked, "What did you do this summer?", you'd go with simple past. Grammar is not always king, context is. "So, what **have you done this summer? What have you been doing this summer?Etc.

Comment: **The only tense that would not work here is present simple**, in fact.

Comment: @Dmitriy It's ambiguous. It would apply equally to a day's labour or a year's.